# R - Group elements of a list that share at least one value

Tags: r, list, merge, grouping

I have a list of vectors in R and I would like to group all the vectors that share at least one value and than keep only the unique values. Do you know how I can code it in R, please?

For example, lets say that the list is the following:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 1 3 7

[[3]]
[1] 3 2 4

[[4]]
[1] 4 3

[[5]]
[1] 17 10

[[6]]
[1] 17 22 10

[[7]]
[1] 22 17
```

I would like to obtain the following two vectors

```
(1,2,3,4,7)
(10,17,22)
```

I was thinking of using a loop where iteratively searching and adding elements that share at least one value with *intersect* and then applying *unique*. However, as my real list contains more than 50000 elements I was wondering if something more efficient exist, please.

Data

```
l <- list(c(1,2),c(2,1,3,7),c(3,2,4),c(4,3),c(17,10),c(17,22,10),c(22,17))
```

Comment: put your list into a data frame `dd <- data.frame(id = rep(seq_along(l), lengths(l)), l = unlist(l))` and your problem becomes [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659114/using-two-grouping-designations-to-create-one-combined-grouping-variable)

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can answer your own question with what you did, upvote, and accept